# Degrees of freedom for successive differences weights

Tags: r, stata, survey

I'm analyzing the American Community Survey integrated public use microdata using the 80 successive differences replicate weights supplied with the 2012-2016 5 Year sample.

I'm following the helpful [guidance](http://asdfree.com/american-community-survey-acs.html) provided by Anthony Damico.

When I call `degf(svrepdesign)` in R, it returns 79, i.e. # replicates - 1.

Can anyone provide some explanation about why this method is used for determining the degrees of freedom in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the rank of the matrix of replicate weights, minus one.  The rationale is explained in a bit more detail here: https://notstatschat.rbind.io/2019/06/08/design-degrees-of-freedom-brief-note/

You can't have more degrees of freedom than the number of replicates, because the variance estimator is a sum of squares of that many things.  Subtracting 1 allows one degree of freedom for calculating a statistic.